# Why is simple product price required even in a configurable product?

Tags: magento-1.9

Some months ago I released a Magento store for the company where I work and they need to change product prices so many times, especially for promo campaigns etc. The point is: because the simple products price being required by default, we have to change, in addition to the configurable product price, each price of their simple products, and it takes us a long time. I read on the internet that simple products are totally useless when working with configurable products, then I wanted to know if there is a possibility of leaving the price field of simple products as optional so we can fill only the configurable products price. Would this affect the operation of something in the store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. However, this will not require price for all products, not just simple.

```
Catalog > Attribute > Manage Attributes > seearch for "price" > Values Requred to "No"
```

If you choose to do this, you have to make sure your configurable products get prices assigned. Otherwise, you'll end up with free products. There might also be some unintended consequences for removing prices from simple products.

Alternatively, there's an `Apply To` section when you're editing an attribute, and you can assign to which product types a given attribute applies. You can try removing simple products from the selection. But again, I'm not sure what the full implication might be for removing prices from simple products.

Comment: Is the price attribute the same for both (simple and configurable) ? Is there some way to remove the price attribute from the attribute group just for simple products, some stuff like that?

Comment: This is not a correct solution. as price wil be omitted for all the types of products

Comment: @joao_house, updated answer.

Comment: @Manashvibirla, feel free to be constructive. Setting `Values Required` to `No` does not omit prices from products. It simply makes them an optional field, which is what the OP asked for.